# Hide Rows That Contain A Certain String Using PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, web, hide, rows

I have this block of PHP code which is pulling its information from a database.

All I want to do is filter/hide the rows that has "Player" like "string".

```
    <?php
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
        echo "<tr>";

        echo "<td>";
        echo $row["player"];
        echo "</td>";

        echo "<td>";
        echo $row["by"];
        echo "</td>";

        echo "</tr>";
    }
    ?>
```

For example I would have a table below:

[image: BEFORE]

And I want it to look like the table below:

[image: AFTER]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using [`strpos()`](http://php.net/strpos) you can check `if (strpos($row["player"], 'String') === false)` and only `echo` if `true`

```
<?php
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{

  if (strpos($row["player"], 'String') === false){

    echo "<tr>";

    echo "<td>";
    echo $row["player"];
    echo "</td>";

    echo "<td>";
    echo $row["by"];
    echo "</td>";

    echo "</tr>";

  }
}
?>
```

Per @Fred-ii's comment-
If you have the possibility of `string` vs `String`, you could use [`stripos()`](http://php.net/stripos) instead of `strpos()`

```
if (stripos($row["player"], 'string') === false)
```

---

**Edit**
Per @Fred-ii's first comment, you could also filter them out in your query, so you don't have to 'hide' them in the php code.

```
SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE player NOT LIKE 'String%'
```

Comment: I think `LIKE` may be better since there are "String" with different numbers following

Comment: @Fred-ii- `LIKE` would be in the mysql query, not the php loop though, correct?

Comment: indeed, yeah ok. I see what you did using `strpos` but since the columns have camel case, it'd probably best to use `stripos`, least I think it'd be best just in case it changes later on to "string" in lowercase. Just an insight.

Comment: That way the OP won't need to worry, should "string" or "STRING" etc. happen to be entered somewhere and if it's coming from user-input or not. Again, just an insight. It won't hurt anything to use it ;-)